# Reading URL #hastag in Laravel controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

I have a URL that has a #hashtag on it. For example

foo.com/foo/location1#tab2

In my routes I would have

```
Route::get('/foo/{loc}', ['uses' => 'FooController@show']);
```

In my controller I would have

```
public function show($loc)
```

What I want to be able to do is read the # value 'tab2' in my controller, but the value of $loc will always be 'location1'. How can I extract the hash value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. The URL hash is not sent to the server. You'll need to add the "tab" part to the URL (in the path or in a query string) or just read it using Javascript.

So, in Laravel you could read:

```
foo.com/foo/location1/tab2
foo.com/foo/location1?tab=2
```

But if you want to use `foo.com/foo/location1#tab2` it needs to be JS.

Comment: Thanks Tomas, explains a frustrating morning.